# Can iPhone show the name of number previosely texted from me?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I am doing sales and contacting a lot of people calling them and texting them. I always write: Dear [person], [message here]

But when someone calls back I don't know who is calling and for me it's very difficult backtrack their details quickly. Is there any kind of hack or app, that can show me the name (related to this number)?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a contact for the number in the Contacts app, your iPhone will then display the name of the caller.

Comment: yes but when those are temporary numbers and I don't want to keep them all in my contacts...

Comment: Have you thought about adding a tag or note to the contact, like "[TEMP] John Doe", creating a Group or something else you can search easily later when you need to delete it? That way you can filter, track and maintain your contacts, instead of just keeping them.

Answer (score -2):

By using "Truecaller" app we can find the contact details globally while he/she calling you but your data (internet) connection should be enable on your device.
Then only the respected person name could appear on screen while calling back to you.